# Unity unit test succeeds even if an exception is thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine

I have EditMode unit test for my Unity project:

```cs
[Test]
public async void TestGetHeroAssetResult()
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse("123");
    var result = await sut.GetHeroAsset(guid);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.AssetType, "type1");
}
```

It throws an exception on run:

```
FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
```

Of course I can fix it. But the problem is the test result is *SUCCESS*.

Is it a normal behavior for Unity tests? How can I force fail this test on exception? Unity version: `2020.3.2f1`. I am newbee to Unity, any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you have to change the signature of the Test to `public async Task TestGetHeroAssetResult()`

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to get failing test. But now it fails every time even when it should succeed. For all who experienced the issue, I found helpful topic about async tests in Unity, take a look https://forum.unity.com/threads/async-await-in-unittests.513857/

Comment: I don't know much about the unity test framework, but modern versions of MsTest and Nunit are able to work with async tests without any problems.

Comment: Unity test framework uses NUnit 3.5, and according to it's async features  it should work as you say. But every time I run test with `async Task` return type I get this: `Method has non-void return value, but no result is expected`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround would be to use a Coroutine test and "manually" wait until the task is finished like e.g.

```
[UnityTest]
public IEnumerator TestGetHeroAssetResult()
{
    var guid = Guid.Parse("123");
    var task = sut.GetHeroAsset(guid);

    while(!task.IsCompleted)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(task.Status, TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
    Assert.AreEqual(task.Result.AssetType, "type1");
}
```

---

Here is an example:

```
public class NewTestScript
{
    private static string[] values = {"123", "12345abcde52ad651234bcde7f123930"};
    
    [UnityTest]
    public IEnumerator NewTestScriptWithEnumeratorPasses([ValueSource(nameof(values))] string value)
    {
        var guid = Guid.Parse(value);
        var task = DoLongTask(guid);

        while(!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(task.Status, TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
        Assert.AreEqual(task.Result, value);
    }

    private async Task<string> DoLongTask(Guid guid)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        return guid.ToString("N");
    }
}
```

Test case 1 fails with the FormatException, case 2 will take 5 seconds and succeeds as expected.

[image]